# Timestamp Format in SQL

Tags: mysql, date, time

I have one Table which has two columns such as "StartTime" and "EndTime". The DataType of the Two columns are Time.

So the Values of the Table looks like as follows:

```
        StartTime                          EndTime
   ------------------                  ----------------
 2014-11-25 02:33:05PM               2014-11-25 02:35:05PM
```

But I need the result as

```
        StartTime                EndTime
   ------------------         ----------------
 2014-11-25 14:33:05        2014-11-25 14:35:05
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(StartTime , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
to_char(EndTime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_FORMAT:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(starttime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') from table
```

See the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for more information about the DATE_FORMAT function.

The uppercase H is for 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CONVERT()` function to display date/time data in different formats.
syntax here

```
CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)
```